# Trying to copy char pointer to "QUERY_STRING" to a char[] variable, getting wrong result

Tags: html, c, fastcgi

I am working with FastCgi, trying to generate a dynamic html webpage.

I am able to get the QUERY_STRING easily enough, but I am having trouble trying to copy it into a char array.

If there is even a shorter way of just getting the value from QUERY_STRING, please advise because I am a little over my head.

```
char *queryString = getenv(ENV_VARS[7]);
char newDeviceName[64];

strncpy( newDeviceName, *queryString, sizeof(*queryString) -1);
printf("------- %c ------------", newDeviceName);
```

This compiles with only warnings, but once i try to load the webpage, the characters are some weird Chinese looking characters. -> �ፙ�

Thank you in advance.

---

EDIT: More of my code

```
const char *ENV_VARS[] = {
    "DOCUMENT_ROOT",
    "HTTP_COOKIE",
    "HTTP_HOST",
    "HTTP_REFERER",
    "HTTP_USER_AGENT",
    "HTTPS",
    "PATH",
    "QUERY_STRING",
    "REMOTE_ADDR",
    "REMOTE_HOST",
    "REMOTE_PORT",
    "REMOTE_USER",
    "REQUEST_METHOD",
    "REQUEST_URI",
    "SCRIPT_FILENAME",
    "SCRIPT_NAME",
    "SERVER_ADMIN",
    "SERVER_NAME",
    "SERVER_PORT",
    "SERVER_SOFTWARE"
};

int main(void)
{
    char deviceName[]=ADAPTERNAME;
    time_t t;
    /* Intializes random number generator */
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0) {

        printf("Content-type: text/html \r\n\r\n");
        printf("");
        printf("<html>\n");
        printf("<script src=\"/js/scripts.js\"></script>");

        /* CODE CODE CODE */

        printf("<p> hi </p>");
        printf("<p> hi </p>");
        char *queryString = getenv(ENV_VARS[7]);
        char newDeviceName[64];
        if (queryString == NULL)
            printf("<p> +++++ERROR++++++ </p>");
        else {
            strcpy( newDeviceName, queryString);
            newDeviceName[sizeof(newDeviceName) - 1] = 0;
            printf("<p> ------- %s ------------ </p> ", newDeviceName);
}
```

---

SOLVED: Amateur mistake, for some reason none of my new edits went into effect until after i restart my lighttpd server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior. **Read those warnings issued by the compiler**. They're important.

---

Don't dereference the pointer when you're passing the string to `strncpy()`. When you do that, you're now passing a single `char`. That's converted to a pointer when it's given to `strncpy()` (which is where you probably get your warning, i.e. passing a `char` to a function that expects a `char*`).

You also can't get the size of an array that has decayed to a pointer using `sizeof`. You're just getting the size of the pointer (which is probably either 8 or 4 bytes depending on your system). Since you don't know the length of the string anyway, it might even be better to just use `strcpy()` instead of `strncpy()`.

---

Here's what your code probably should look like:

```
char *queryString = getenv(ENV_VARS[7]);
char newDeviceName[64];

strcpy( newDeviceName, queryString);
printf("------- %s ------------", newDeviceName); /* use %s to print strings */
```

Comment: Same as another answer, i get a segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: @CluelessIntern Are you sure there's actual content in `queryString` and not just junk or `NULL`?

Comment: (copy and paste from another comment) Aha! You are right about it returning null, i missed that. Problem now is, in the browser it's not showing any text.. only those funky symbols.

Comment: @CluelessIntern What's `queryString` actually pointing to before you copy it to `newDeviceName`? Your buffer could be too small.

Comment: `const char *ENV_VARS[] = {
    "QUERY_STRING",
};`

Comment: @CluelessIntern Okay. There's your problem. `queryString` is pointing to garbage. `ENV_VARS[7]` is outside the bounds of the array. You're not supposed to access it. Doing that is undefined behavior.

Comment: ENV_VARS[] actually does have more than 1 element, i only included the one i was using. I will post a larger snippet of code in the main post

Comment: @CluelessIntern try changing the size of `newDeviceName` to something larger, like `512`. Otherwise, I have no idea. Your code looks fine now.

Comment: Solved it, for some reason the changes didnt go into effect until after i restarted the server.

Answer (score 0):

The length on your `strncpy` is wrong [too short], the second argument is wrong, and the format string is incorrect.

Try this:

```
strncpy( newDeviceName, queryString, sizeof(newDeviceName) - 1);
newDeviceName[sizeof(newDeviceName) - 1] = 0;
printf("------- %s ------------", newDeviceName);
```

Comment: We posted simultaneously, but I missed the middle line. Due credit to dbush's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the call to `strncpy`, it expects a `char *` for the second argument, but you pass it a `char`.

Also, the size is not correct.  `*queryString` is a `char` and has size 1.  Using `sizeof(queryString)` is not correct either because it will return the size of a pointer.  What you actually want is the size of the detination buffer.

In the `printf` call the `%c` format specifier expects a `char` but you pass it a `char *`.  You should instead use `%s` which expects a `char *` pointing to a null terminated string.

So what you want to do is this:

```
strncpy( newDeviceName, queryString, sizeof(newDeviceName) -1);
newDeviceName[sizeof(newDeviceName) - 1] = 0;
printf("------- %s ------------", newDeviceName);
```

Comment: `\0` would be preferable to bare `0`, just on a style note

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
strncpy(newDeviceName, queryString, sizeof(newDeviceName)-1);
newDeviceName[63] = '\0'; // Guarantee NUL terminator
printf("----- %s -----", newDeviceName);
```

So multiple problems:

- `*queryString` just gets you the first character, which `strncpy` tries to treat as a pointer.
- `sizeof(*queryString)` is the size of a char (i.e. 1)
- `%c` prints a single character, not the string

Comment: I get segmentation fault (core dumped) on execution.

Comment: Aha! You are right about it returning null, i missed that.  Problem now is, in the browser it's not showing any text.. only those funky symbols.  I added an if statement to check for the null, and in the terminal it works, but the browser is not showing me any text.*